# Angular 1.3.15 : Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
app.js

'use strict';

/* App Module */

var springChat = angular.module('springChat', ['springChat.controllers',
                                               'springChat.services',
                                               'springChat.directives']);


contrillers.js


'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('springChat.controllers', ['toaster'])
 .controller('ChatController', ['$scope', '$location', '$interval', 'toaster', 'ChatSocket', function($scope, $location, $interval, toaster, chatSocket) {
    
  var typing = undefined;
  
  $scope.from     = '';
  $scope.sendTo       = 'everyone';
  $scope.participants = [];
  $scope.messages     = [];
  $scope.newMessage   = ''; 
    
  $scope.sendMessage = function() {
   var destination = "/app/chat";
   
   if($scope.sendTo != "everyone") {
    destination = "/app/private." + $scope.sendTo;
    $scope.messages.unshift({message: $scope.newMessage, from: 'you', priv: true, to: $scope.sendTo});
   }
   
   chatSocket.send(destination, {}, JSON.stringify({message: $scope.newMessage}));
   $scope.newMessage = '';
  };
  
  $scope.startTyping = function() {
   // Don't send notification if we are still typing or we are typing a private message
         if (angular.isDefined(typing) || $scope.sendTo != "everyone") return;
         
         typing = $interval(function() {
                 $scope.stopTyping();
             }, 500);
         
         chatSocket.send("/topic/chat.typing", {}, JSON.stringify({from: $scope.from, typing: true}));
  };
  
  $scope.stopTyping = function() {
   if (angular.isDefined(typing)) {
          $interval.cancel(typing);
          typing = undefined;
          
          chatSocket.send("/topic/chat.typing", {}, JSON.stringify({from: $scope.from, typing: false}));
   }
  };
  
  $scope.privateSending = function(from) {
    $scope.sendTo = (from != $scope.sendTo) ? from : 'everyone';
  };
   
  var initStompClient = function() {
   chatSocket.init('/ws');
   
   chatSocket.connect(function(frame) {
      
    $scope.from = frame.headers['user-name'];

    chatSocket.subscribe("/app/participants", function(message) {
     $scope.participants = JSON.parse(message.body);
    });
      
    chatSocket.subscribe("/topic/chat.login", function(message) {
     $scope.participants.unshift({from: JSON.parse(message.body).from, typing : false});
    });
            
    chatSocket.subscribe("/topic/chat.logout", function(message) {
     var from = JSON.parse(message.body).from;
     for(var index in $scope.participants) {
      if($scope.participants[index].from == from) {
       $scope.participants.splice(index, 1);
      }
     }
          });
            
    chatSocket.subscribe("/topic/chat.typing", function(message) {
     var parsed = JSON.parse(message.body);
     if(parsed.from == $scope.from) return;
           
     for(var index in $scope.participants) {
      var participant = $scope.participants[index];
        
      if(participant.from == parsed.from) {
       $scope.participants[index].typing = parsed.typing;
      }
       } 
    });
            
    chatSocket.subscribe("/topic/message", function(message) {
     $scope.messages.unshift(JSON.parse(message.body));
          });
      
    chatSocket.subscribe("/user/exchange/amq.direct/message", function(message) {
     var parsed = JSON.parse(message.body);
     parsed.priv = true;
     $scope.messages.unshift(parsed);
          });
      
    chatSocket.subscribe("/user/exchange/amq.direct/errors", function(message) {
     toaster.pop('error', "Error", message.body);
          });
            
   }, function(error) {
    toaster.pop('error', 'Error', 'Connection error ' + error);
    
      });
  };
    
  initStompClient();
 }]);
 

services.js

'use strict';

/* Services */

angular.module('springChat.services', [])
 .factory('ChatSocket', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
   var stompClient;
   
   var wrappedSocket = {
     
     init: function(url) {
      stompClient = Stomp.over(new SockJS(url));
     },
     connect: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
      
      stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
       $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        successCallback(frame);
       });
      }, function(error) {
       $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        errorCallback(error);
       });
            });
     },
     subscribe : function(destination, callback) {
      stompClient.subscribe(destination, function(message) {
         $rootScope.$apply(function(){
          callback(message);
         });
              }); 
     },
     send: function(destination, headers, object) {
      stompClient.send(destination, headers, object);
     }
   }
   
   return wrappedSocket;
  
 }]);


directives.js

/* Directives */

angular.module('springChat.directives', [])
 .directive('printMessage', function () {
     return {
      restrict: 'A',
         template: '<span ng-show="message.priv">[private] </span><strong>{{message.from}}<span ng-show="message.to"> -> {{message.to}}</span>:</strong> {{message.message}}<br/>'
        
     };
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="springChat">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Chat WebSocket</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
     <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/sockjs-0.3.4.js" var="js1" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/stomp.js" var="js2" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/chat.js" var="js3" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/app.js" var="js4" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/controllers.js" var="js5" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/directives.js" var="js6" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" var="js7" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/angular-animate.min.js" var="js9" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/toaster.js" var="js10" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/scrollglue.js" var="js11" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/sockjs.min.js" var="js12" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/js/stomp.min.js" var="js13" />
  
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/css/pages/bootstrap.min.css" var="css1" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/css/flat-ui.css" var="css2" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/css/toaster.css" var="css3" />
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="cs" /> 
  <spring:url value="/resources/common/css/chat.css" var="css4" />
  
      <script src="${js}"></script>
      <script src="${js1}"></script> 
      <script src="${js2}"></script> 
      <script src="${js3}"></script>      
      <script src="${js4}"></script>
      <script src="${js5}"></script>
      <script src="${js6}"></script>
      <script src="${js7}"></script> 
      <script src="${js8}"></script> 
      <script src="${js9}"></script>      
      <script src="${js10}"></script>
      <script src="${js11}"></script>
      <script src="${js12}"></script>
      <script src="${js13}"></script>
  
      <link href="${cs}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="${css1}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="${css2}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="${css3}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="${css4}" rel="stylesheet">
       
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var typing = false;
    var timeout = undefined;
    var typingDelayMillis = 500;
    var user = document.getElementById('from').textContent;
    
    function timeoutFunction() {
        typing = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "typing",
            data : {
             user_name: user 
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    
    success : function(user_name) {
     $('#typing').html("");
    }
   });
        }
    var delay = (function() {
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    });

    $('#text').keyup(function(e) {
        if (typing === false && $("#text").is(":focus")) {
            delay(function() {
                timeoutFunction();
            }, typingDelayMillis);
            typing = true;
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "typing",
              data : {
               user_name:user 
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success : function(user_name) {
     $('#typing').html(user_name);
    }
   });
         }
    });

    $('#text').on("blur", function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, typingDelayMillis);
    })
});
/* var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 10;
var finaldoneTypingInterval = 500;

var oldData = $("#typing").html();
$(document).ready(function() {
 var typingTimer;
 var doneTypingInterval = 10;
 var finaldoneTypingInterval = 500;
 var oldData = $("#typing").html();
 
$('#text').keydown(function () {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#text').val()) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#typing").html('Typing...');
        }, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
 var typingTimer;
 var doneTypingInterval = 10;
 var finaldoneTypingInterval = 500;
 var oldData = $("#typing").html();
 $('#text').keyup(function () {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#typing").html(oldData);
    }, finaldoneTypingInterval);
});
});*/

/* var timer = 0;
function reduceTimer(){
timer = timer - 1;
isTyping(true);
}
function isTyping(val){
if(val == 'true'){
var user= document.getElementById('from').textContent;
document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = (user + " is typing...");
}else{

if(timer <= 0){
document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = "";
}else{
setTimeout("reduceTimer();",500);
}
}
}*/
</script>

</head>   
<body onload="disconnect()">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ChatController">
   <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-embossed" role="navigation">
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-01">              
             <h3>Welcome  <i id="from" class="username" value="${username}">${username}</i>
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                                
                <li class="dropdown-toggle"><a id="connect" onclick="connect();">CONNECT</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-toggle"><a id="disconnect" style="visibility: hidden" onclick="disconnect();">DISCONNECT</a></li>
               </ul></h3>
              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav><!-- /navbar -->
   </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
           <h4>Participants</h4>
           <div id="list" class="share">                                 
            <ul ng-repeat="participant in participants">
            <small print-message></small>
           <a href=""><p id="participant">${user}</p></a> 
               <li>               
              <span class="input-icon fui-new" ng-show="participant.typing"></span>
              <span class="input-icon fui-user" ng-show="!participant.typing"></span>
              <a href="" ng-click="privateSending(participant.from)"></a> 
             </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8 chat-box">
           <h4>Messages</h4>
           <div id="scroll" style="height:400px;width:975px;border:solid 2px white;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;">
             <small print-message></small>
         <p id="response"></p>
         <div id="chatArea" style="width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: auto">
          </div>
          </div>
         </div>
     <!--   <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <span><small>You will send this message to <strong>{{sendTo}}</strong> (click a participant name to send a private message)</small></span>
      <input id="newMessageInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your message and hit enter..." ng-model="newMessage" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? sendMessage() : startTyping()"/>
    </div>  -->
         </div> 
         
      <div id="conversationDiv">
        <p class="content"></p>
        <div id="typing"></div>
        <span><small>You will send this message to <strong>{{sendTo}}</strong> (click a participant name to send a private message)</small></span>
     <input type="text" id="text" name="message" ng-model="newMessage" placeholder="Type Message ..." class="form-control">
        <div>   <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="submit" id="sendMessage" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" onclick="sendMessage();">Send</button>
                  </span></div>
              <!--     <label>
<textarea onkeypress="isTyping('true'); timer=5;" onkeyup="isTyping('false')" name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
</label>
<div id="typing_on">No one is typing at the moment.</div>  -->
              </div>
        </div>
       </header>
      </body>
</html>
```

when i try to run my chat application it shows,

> angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=springChat&p1=Erro…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A179)(…)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4138r @ angular.js:323 g @angular.js:323

Comment: Where is the actual controller? There is a module called "springChat" that we are not seeing how it is being used

Comment: Please provide code example where you get this error

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to include that file in index.html or it could be you forgot to include it in angular.module.